# c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places. with , every 1000

Tags: c#

So always add a comma and have it to two decimal places, `"F"` nearly works but can't find the right solution

```
decimal = 1000.5

test.Text = decimal.ToString("F")
```

I've also tried:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###.##}", decimal);
```

I want to display as the string as `1,000.50`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###.00}", decimalNumber);
```

See: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> 0 - Zero placeholder Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if
>   one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string. [More
>   information: The "0" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0).

*It is not going to round the numbers, it is just string formatting.*

For culture insensitive formatting do:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:#,###.00}", decimalNmber);
```

Comment: that gives exactly the same output with `String.Format("{0:#,###.##}")`

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't

Comment: @Selman22, it shouldn't `#` is for optional digits and `0` is replaced with any digit if present otherwise 0

Comment: @Selman22, what is the number you are trying if it already has 2 decimal places then you will see the same output from both formats

Comment: @Habib sorry you were right.I didn't even notice the leading zero, I get `1.000,50` (comma and dot order is wrong) I think it is about my culture. +1

Comment: An easier way is to use the [Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString).

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0,0.00}", decimal)
```

For more options see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And [here](https://ideone.com/SX5bui) you can test this online.